# Spring Batch - How to set chunk > 1 when items have interdependencies?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job that needs to write all items to a DB in one chunk. I want this behavior because

1. I need to do some validation involving comparisons among the read items prior to writing.
2. If any validation fails, I need to make sure that no items are persisted or all items are persisted.
3. It's a small amount of data < 60kb.

The item is a `Car` and it has a `Model` property. The problem that I'm having is that part of the item processing checks to see if the `Model` already exists in the database. If it does, it retrieves the model from the DB (including auto generated id) and therefore does not create another DB entry.

Now, that works fine if the `Model` was already persisted in a previous job run. However, it fails when the same `Model` shows up for two different `Car`s in the same job run and the `Model` was not persisted previously. In that case, two database rows get created for the same `Model`.

I'm using JPA with `Model` having an id property annotated with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. How can I ensure prior to writing that the same `Model` is not written to the database more than once?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect this is happening because each chunk is comprised of a transaction, and you're performing validation and writes for multiple elements within that single transaction, and one of the writes could invalidate the validation of another item to be written.

If you really want to use the chunk-oriented processing in this case, it seems like you just need to implement some sort of caching solution in your `ItemProcessor`. When you create a new `Model`, you would then store an identifier for that model in something like a `Set`. Every time the processor processes a `Car` item, it checks the cache, then checks the database for an existing model prior to creating a new one.

Otherwise, you could avoid the chunk-oriented processing entirely by using a simple Tasklet step. With this, you would have full control over the logical transactions. The primary reason to do chunk-oriented processing is so that you can write a big chunk of items all at once to gain efficiency. Since you're doing extra validation with the database for each item, you're losing some of that benefit.

If your `Model` table is small enough, you could cache it and then do all of the validation in-memory.

Comment: Could you please provide more thoughts on what the `Takslet` step would do?  Would it do the reading, processing and writing? 

I'm not sure how the caching solution of the `ItemProcessor` will work. Are you suggesting that the `ItemProcessor` persists each new `Model` it finds in the DB (prior to the `ItemWriter`)? A `Car` cannot have a null `Model`. If the `Model` is not null but has a null `id` it will be considered a new `Model`. 

The `Model` table is small enough to cache in-memory. Thanks.

Comment: The `Tasklet` step would indeed do the reading, processing, and writing, but it doesn't necessarily have to follow that paradigm. You can think of it as a custom method that iterates through the `Car` elements coming in, validates each one, and persists it, as well as the new `Model` if there is one. The chunk-oriented processing (reader/processor/writer) is often overkill and getting it to handle certain scenarios is sometimes more difficult than its worth.

You could always just leave the chunk size at 1, unless it the performance is causing a significant problem.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I cannot not leave the chunk size at 1 because the system must persist all items (i.e. `Car`s) or none of the items. It must not persist just some of the items. I'm not sure how the `Tasklet` is benefiting me here.

Comment: Also, I'm using JPA. So, if `Model` has no id, it creates a new row when persisting `Car`. Since I'm must persist all `Car`s in one transaction, each `Car`'s `Model` will get persisted as a new row in the DB (even if the `Model`s are the same (i.e. `equals()`). After much more thought, I think that I have a couple of solutions to this now. I'll post the answer. I'll accept your answer if it is a better solution but right now I'm unsure how it would help meet the requirements / solve the issues noted in the OP. Thanks again for your input thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to solve for this issue:

1. Create a first `Step` to read/process/write `Model`s
2. In the `ItemProcessor<Car>`, check if the `Model` is in the DB as is currently being done. If it's not in the DB, go ahead and write it to the DB prior to writing all of the `Car`s.

The disadvantages to option 1 is that: 1) the file is read twice (once for `Model`s and once for `Car`s). 2) If the `Car` step fails, you could have `Model`s  with no associated `Car`s.

Option 2 will involve more hits to the DB. However, the numbers of records is small. Also, the `Model` writes to the DB is in the same transaction as the write for all of the `Car`s. So, if `Car`s fail to persist so will its associated `Model`s.